# Applying patch file in drupal

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-6

I am working on a drupal application and I need to apply a patch to one of the files.
The name of patch file is db_close.patch and the file name to which this patch has to be applied is databasefile.inc in projectname/includes folder.

What is the command line in linux to apply the patch file?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The command line is `man patch`

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But is the patch file name or path to the file not necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I’m messing with you. The exact command depends on the format of the patch file. You could try `patch projectname/include/databasefile.inc < db_close.patch`.